# Filtering object properties based on value

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

Is there some elegant way of filtering out falsey properties from this object with lodash/underscore? Similar to how `_.compact(array)` removes falsey elements from arrays

so from

```
{
  propA: true,
  propB: true,
  propC: false,
  propD: true,
}
```

returning

```
{
  propA: true,
  propB: true,
  propD: true,
}
```

Comment: **ES6 syntax:** ```Object.keys(obj).filter((key) => obj[key])```

Comment: @DimitrijeM that would return an array of keys, not an object.

Comment: hey @DimitrijeM, +1, shouldn't you put this in an answer to give more visibility? thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Lodash 4.0

Lodash 4.0 has `_.pick`, which takes an array of properties, and `_.pickBy` which takes a function as an argument and returns an object only containing the keys for which that function returns truthy which is what we want here, so it'd be:

```
filtered = _.pickBy(obj, function(value, key) {return value;})
```

Or, since `_.pickBy` defaults to using `_.identity` as it's second argument, (and that's essentially what we've written above,) it can just be written as:

```
filtered = _.pickBy(obj);
```

### Underscore or Lodash prior to version 4.0

In underscore and old versions of lodash, there's just a single `_.pick`, which has both behaviors of `_.pick` and `_.pickWith` from v4. So you can do:

```
filtered = _.pick(obj, function(value, key) {return value;})
```

Or more succinctly:

```
filtered = _.pick(obj, _.identity)
```

Answer (score 36):

Here are two vanilla javascript options:

**A.:** Iterate over the object's keys and [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) those having a falsey value.

```js
var obj = {
  propA: true,
  propB: true,
  propC: false,
  propD: true,
};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
  if (!obj[key]) delete obj[key];
});

console.log(obj);
```

<sub>See `Object.keys()` and `Array.prototype.forEach()`</sub>

**B.:** Iterate over the object's keys and add truthy values to a new object.

```js
var obj = {
  propA: true,
  propB: true,
  propC: false,
  propD: true,
};

var filteredObj = Object.keys(obj).reduce((p, c) => {    
  if (obj[c]) p[c] = obj[c];
  return p;
}, {});

console.log(filteredObj);
```

<sub>See `Object.keys()` and `Array.prototype.reduce()`</sub>

Answer (score 4):

As partially mentioned in a comment, ES6 provided [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and in 2019 [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

Allowing:

```
Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([key, value]) => ...))
```

Ex:

```
const obj = {
  a: 12,
  b: 123,
};

const filteredObj = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj).filter(
    ([_, value]) => value > 100
  )
);

console.log(filteredObj);
// {b: 123}
```

Answer (score 2):

*Unfortunately I cannot direclty comment on the posts above yet, so I create this extra post.*

Since Lodash v4 the functionality described above has been moved to [_.pickBy](https://lodash.com/docs#pickBy). With `_.identity` as default you could also change your code to:

```
var filtered = _.pickBy(obj);
```

See this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wodiyosemo/edit?js,console) for a working example.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using lodash, I'd recommend something like this:

```
var object = {
    propA: true,
    propB: true,
    propC: false,
    propD: true,
};

_.pick(object, _.identity);
// →
// {
//   propA: true,
//   propB: true,
//   propD: true
// }
```

The [pick()](https://lodash.com/docs#pick) function generates a new object that includes properties that the callback returns *truthy* for. So we can just use the [identity()](https://lodash.com/docs#identity) function as the callback, since it'll just return each property value.

Answer (score 0):

From lodash 4, we can use pickBy() to get only the value equal to true.

```
const active = _.keys(_.pickBy(object));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let temp = {
  propA: true,
  propB: true,
  propC: false,
  propD: true,
}

let obj = {}
for(x in temp){
   if(temp[x] == true){
     obj[x] = temp[x]
   }
}

console.log(obj)
```

Using for-in loop we can achieve it something like this.

Comment: The question specifically asks how to perform this using either lodash or underscore. This is also a five year old question with an accepted answer which would mean that any new answers that are added should be pointing out what new aspect of the question they address.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach

```
const objFilter = (obj, condition) => {
    let newObj = {}
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        if (condition(value)) {
            newObj = { ...newObj, [key]: value }
        }
    }
    return newObj
}
```

Fire like this:

```
const newData = objFilter(oldData, (value) => value.marked === false)
```