# Filter object properties by value integer

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, javascript-objects, lodash

Is there a way in underscore to filter properties in an object if the values are numbers? I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29282273/filtering-object-properties-based-on-value), but it deals with booleans.

I want to filter object properties with values greater than one.

From:

```
[{
  "Tom"  : 10,
  "Dick" : 5,
  "Harry": 0,
  "date" : "02/23/2010
}]
```

To:

```
[{
  "Tom"  : 10,
  "Dick" : 5,
  "date" : "02/23/2010
}]
```

I've looked at the underscore documentation and thought `_.pick` or `_.omit` would do the trick, but they only focus on keys.

I've also tried `_.filter` with `_.values` as the argument.

Comment: How is the last one processed as a number?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen for `date`?

Comment: *"I've seen this question, but it deals with booleans."* And you can't imagine how it could be changed to handle numbers?

Comment: @epascarello Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: The last entry "date" is not a number, it is a string. So how are you saying it is a number greater than 1?

Comment: I'd like the date to remain. I'll just write a conditional to ignore strings.

Comment: Why doesn't the answer to the other question solve your problem? The function you give to `_.pick()` can do anything it wants with the value, including checking whether it's a number and greater than 1. You don't have to use the same function in that question, just use the same general structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just remove properties that don't satisfy a certain condition.

```
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj[key] < 1) {
        delete obj[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped. Thank you!